# set up for making a chrome extension that gets snippets?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make an extension that would help me get effective notes better and one thing I thought of is just highlighting certain snippets from web page and putting them in a bookmark.  I haven't done any extensions before but I have the basics of coding down and also researched on how to make an extension in regards to creating a manifest.json.

Would help if there is anyone that can give some basic starting info or code?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by reading the Chrome documentation ...

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

I mean ... this is a broad topic. The documentation above has a walkthrough which covers creating the `manifest.json`. As far as the rest of your efforts are concerned, you probably should take a crack at it, and ask specific questions as they arise.